# Неполучаестся выполнить запрос в mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Не могу понять почему не выводятся данные.
В чем у меня состоит задача:
Необходимо ввести даты с 2022-02-07 по 2022-02-09 c выбором фамилии
То есть фильтрация по фамилии  с 2022-02-07 по 2022-02-08
если я ввожу запрос

SELECT  * from base WHERE fio LIKE 'иванов%' and  DATA='2022-02-07
все отлично выдает
когда человек пришел и ушел.

А так пустые данные
SELECT  * from base WHERE fio LIKE 'иванов%' and  DATA='2022-02-07' and DATA ='2022-02-09'

Вот сама таблица
fio,data,time,value

Что я сделал не так.

Comment: ... and (DATA='2022-02-07' OR DATA ='2022-02-09')

Comment: Спасибо работает. Но мне нужно с '2022-02-07  по '2022-02-09  и если есть приход или уход 2022-02-09  то есть записи от и до.

Comment: ... and between '2022-02-07' and '2022-02-09'

Comment: название поля потерял =)  ... and DATA between '2022-02-07' and '2022-02-09'

Comment: Ошибка SELECT  * from base WHERE fio LIKE 'иванов%'  AND and between '2022-02-07' and '2022-02-09'

Comment: SELECT  * from base WHERE fio LIKE 'иванов%'  and  between DATA='2022-02-07' and DATA='2022-02-09' Тоже ошибка

Answer (score 0):

используйте Between датаначала And датазавершения:

```
 SELECT * from base WHERE fio LIKE 'иванов%' AND and DATA between '2022-02-07' and '2022-02-09'
```

Comment: Спасибо большое заработало